# Careers 2.0 Invite Acceptance Failure

Tags: support, jobs

I just got an invite to careers, and tried accepting it. The basic information page asked for my name and email. When I submitted, it said my email had been found as an SO user (I'm always logged in). It said I needed to log out and back in for some reason. I did that, and when I came back, I still didn't have a CV. But I tried to go back to my invite, and it told me that it has already been claimed. So now I don't have a profile or an invite. I have no idea what happened. Any help here? Did I accidentally waste my invite on a not-logged-in guest user of the careers site?

Comment: You should be all set now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it's helpful. I found the issue, and we'll fix it.  Basically, you had two accounts in the system (one of which was created automatically).  You were logged in as one, accepted the invite, tried to create a profile but couldn't because the email was already registered, then you logged out and logged in as the other which didn't have an invitation.

We've merged the two accounts, and are working on a way to automatically detect this in the future.

In general, this issue affects a small number of users, so if anyone runs into any problems, email careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll sort you out.

Comment: @David - would it make sense to prevent the invitation going out if the recipient is already registered. Obviously this will fail if the inviter uses a different e-mail address, but might get 90% of cases.

Comment: No luck it seems. Still got the same "log back in" message and still getting the "How do I get one?" page for my profile.

Comment: @Tesserex I believe this was resolved over email?